# Accidentally submitting posts when editing tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts, tag-autocomplete

This is a user problem, but I've made this mistake almost every time I've edited tags on a question. I start to type a tag name, and the completion pops up:

[image: Screenshot of the tag editor, still in the text field]

"Hey!", I think. "There's my tag right there!". I haven't actually selected it; I'm supposed to hit <kbd>Down</kbd> so this happens:

[image: Screenshot of the tag editor with a tag selected]

But I don't, because I'm an idiot. So I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the form gets submitted, even though I wasn't done. Can it be changed so that <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't submit the form if the tag editor is open? It can either select the top tag or do nothing; whichever seems better

Comment: We are all idiots (Dilbert Principle). Good point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if you're an idiot, but at least you're useful.

[image: Humorisitc combination of a depiction of a felis catus with a collection of orthographically suboptimally connected graphemes]

Good point, added to the next build!